# Defining out-groups in MEGA

Tags: phylogenetics

I am using the MEGA software for trimming protein sequences and building phylogenetic trees.

How can I define out-groups of phylogenetic tree in MEGA? Is there a way to calculate the distances of each species from the root?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.... the issue is that the precise location of the root - unless it's a molecular clock - is arbitrarily assigned within limits. You can designate populations ('clades') and ask for the genetic distance between the clades, it's one of the menus header options. To do what you want you need to build the tree (neighbor-joining method) and assess it in the pop-up window. Switch the view of the tree to 'genetic distance' and then manually add the branch lengths for each root - tip distance. One of the Beast supporting packages use to calculate the root tip distance, I think this option was removed in the upgrades.